# Using 'sed' or 'awk' for a data conversion task

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have data in this format (many lines like this):

```
TASK : Task 1  
TASK : Task 2  
TASK : Task 3  
OWNER : Emp 1  
OWNER : Emp 2  
OWNER : Emp 3  
Deadline : Monday  
Deadline : Tuesday  
Deadline : Wednesday
```

This, I want to convert to:

```
TASK          OWNER           Deadline
Task 1       Emp 1            Monday  
Task 2       Emp 2            Tuesday  
Task 3       Emp 3            Wednesday
```

Even if I can just extract each column without the column header names it'd be good. I can add the column names manually afterwards.

Is there a way to do it using 'awk' or 'sed' ?

Comment: I don't think 'sed' will get you far, as it parses a document line by line. Working across multiple lines is a real headache...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one way with awk:

```
 awk -F': *' '{i=NR%3;i=i?i:3;a[i]=a[i]?a[i]"\t"$2:$2}
              END{for(x=1;x<=length(a);x++)print a[x]}' file
```

it keeps the order, omits the header line:

```
kent$  cat f
TASK : Task 1  
TASK : Task 2  
TASK : Task 3  
OWNER : Emp 1  
OWNER : Emp 2  
OWNER : Emp 3  
Deadline : Monday  
Deadline : Tuesday  
Deadline : Wednesday 

kent$  awk -F': *' '{i=NR%3;i=i?i:3;a[i]=a[i]?a[i]"\t"$2:$2}END{for(x=1;x<=length(a);x++)print a[x]}' f
Task 1          Emp 1   Monday  
Task 2          Emp 2   Tuesday  
Task 3          Emp 3   Wednesday
```

#### explanation

```
 awk -F': *'             #":any <space>" as FS
 '{i=NR%3;i=i?i:3;       #take NR%3 in i, if i=0, set i=3. because
                         #we want the i=0 case at the end of the output
 a[i]=a[i]?a[i]"\t"$2:$2}#concatenate the 2nd column to an array
 END{for and print}' file#print the content of the array at the end
```

#### Header

we can save the header in a var `h` and print it out before go through the `a (array)`:

```
awk -F': *' '{...h=i==1?(h?h"\t"$1:$1):h;a[i]=..} 
END{print h;for...}' file
```

Comment: Good one! For the header you can maybe read the file twice, so that on the first shot you store all options: `-F: 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$1; next}`, etc.

Comment: @fedorqui that's one way. in fact going through the file once for the head is enough. just take and concatenate the `$1` when `NR%3==certain value(0 or 1 or 2)`

Comment: This is brilliant. I accepted your answer.. If it's not too much trouble could you also add a small explanation of how this works? Will help me in building these commands by myself in future!

Comment: @sanjeevmk added explanation and the header handling. Note that the `3` in above codes was hardcoded, but it could be a variable. you can get the number by other magic tools like `grep, awk or your eyes ...`

Comment: @Kent: When I run this on 3.1.3 it says "FNR=9) fatal: attempt to use array `a' in a scalar context" Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a relatively nice `awk` version:

```
BEGIN {FS=" : ";OFS="\t"}

/^TASK/     {task [tpos++] = $2}
/^OWNER/    {owner[opos++] = $2}
/^Deadline/ {due  [dpos++] = $2}

END {
  print "TASK", "OWNER", "DEADLINE"
  for (i in task) {
    print task[i],owner[i],due[i]
  }
}
```

:)

It saves a line per block because it does not need the `gsub()` call as it is using the `:` as the delimiter. Store it in, lets say, `test.awk` and execute it as follows:

```
awk -f test.awk input.txt
```

---

**Update**:

The above command leads to unaligned output in the shell:

```
TASK    OWNER    DEADLINE
Task 1      Emp 1      Monday  
Task 2      Emp 2      Tuesday  
Task 3      Emp 3      Wednesday
```

You can fix this using the `column` command:

```
awk -f test.awk input.txt | column -t -s $'\t'
```

Now the output looks clean:

```
TASK      OWNER    DEADLINE
Task 1    Emp 1    Monday  
Task 2    Emp 2    Tuesday  
Task 3    Emp 3    Wednesday
```

Comment: That _is_ much nicer, +1.

Comment: ;) Your variable names are cleaner, but I don't wanted to copy it. It's definitely better to use descriptive variable names when deciding to make a script rather than a one liner out of it. Yours and my combined would be the "nicest"! :)

Comment: Nah, don't worry about that, I'd rather delete my answer and just add the full variables to yours. It's not like I'm possessive about code I post here, it's _supposed_ to be used or "stolen". I added the longer vars and fixed a few minor typos. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
perl -le 'while (<>) {
              chomp;
              ($h, $t) = split / : /;
              $i++, push @{$ar[0]}, $h if $h ne $ar[0][-1];
              push @{$ar[$i]}, $t;
          };
          $" = "\t";
          print "@{$ar[0]}";
          print join $", map shift @{$ar[$_]}, 1 .. $#ar while @{$ar[1]}'
```

If the tabs didn't align the text nicely, I'd use [Text::Table](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aTable).